# CSS search button style being overridden by User Agent Stylesheet

Tags: html, css

When the code below renders in ANY browser, the user agent stylesheet is overriding the form.example in my CSS for the search button. The button is appearing small and not the same size as the input box as it used to. I have confirmed this using the browser console. It's strange because the same CSS has been working fine for months and I haven't changed anything. It stopped working all of a sudden. Strangely, when I run the same code in https://www.codeply.com/p it seems to render correctly.

Here is code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Courier New, monospace; color: white;
}

{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Courier New, monospace; color: white;
}

/* Style the top navigation bar */
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Courier New, monospace;
}

/* Style the topnav links */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(48, 10, 36);
  color: black;
}

/* Style the content */
.content {
  background-color: rgb(48, 10, 36);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%; /*Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}
table,
td {
    border: 1px solid #333;

}

thead,
tfoot {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Style the footer bar */
.footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Courier New, monospace;
}

/* Style the footer links */
.footer a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.footer a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(48, 10, 36);
  color: black;
}

/* Style the footer

 .footer {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}
*/
/* Style the search box */

input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;/* CSS for search file */
body {
  font-family: Courier New, monospace;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form.example
  width: 80%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

}
table.example
  width: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

form.example button {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
form.example button:hover {
  background: #0b7dda;
}
form.example::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Ramster</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/index.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, height=100%">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="home">Home</a>
      <a href="search">Leagues</a>
      <a href="teams">Teams</a>
      <a href="insert">Players</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <h2>Ramster</h2>
      <p>A place to play</p>
      <form class="example" method="post" action="" style="margin:left;max-width:600px">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search by team or player" name="name">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <table class="example">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="1">Name</th>
            <th colspan="1">Position</th>
            <th colspan="1">Team</th>
            <th colspan="1">Buy</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for item in data %}
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
            <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
            <td>{{item[3]}}</td>
            <td><a href="getPlayer?playerid={{item[0]}}" style="color:#E95420">Buy</a></td>
            {% endfor %}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="showLogin">Login</a>
      <a href="showRegister">Register</a>
      <a href="logout">Logout</a>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `{` in form.example and got one closing `}` to much after it. Therefore its missing on `input[type=text] {`

Should work:

```
form.example {
  width: 80%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;/* CSS for search file */
 }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wm84daqo/)

**OR**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Courier New, monospace; color: white;
}

{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Courier New, monospace; color: white;
}

/* Style the top navigation bar */
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Courier New, monospace;
}

/* Style the topnav links */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(48, 10, 36);
  color: black;
}

/* Style the content */
.content {
  background-color: rgb(48, 10, 36);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%; /*Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}
table,
td {
    border: 1px solid #333;

}

thead,
tfoot {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Style the footer bar */
.footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Courier New, monospace;
}

/* Style the footer links */
.footer a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.footer a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(48, 10, 36);
  color: black;
}

/* Style the footer

 .footer {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}
*/
/* Style the search box */

input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;/* CSS for search file */
 }
  
body {
  font-family: Courier New, monospace;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form.example {
  width: 80%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}


table.example {
  width: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

form.example button {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

form.example button:hover {
  background: #0b7dda;
}
form.example::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Ramster</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/index.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, height=100%">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="home">Home</a>
        <a href="search">Leagues</a>
        <a href="teams">Teams</a>
        <a href="insert">Players</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <h2>Ramster</h2>
        <p>A place to play</p>
        <form class="example" method="post" action="" style="display:inline;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search by team or player" name="name">
                    <button type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
                <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
            <table class="example">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="1">Name</th>
                            <th colspan="1">Position</th>
                            <th colspan="1">Team</th>
                            <th colspan="1">Buy</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    {% for item in data %}
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
                            <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
                            <td>{{item[3]}}</td>
                            <td><a href="getPlayer?playerid={{item[0]}}" style="color:#E95420">Buy</a></td>
                    {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
    </div>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="showLogin">Login</a>
        <a href="showRegister">Register</a>
        <a href="logout">Logout</a>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did notice this however changing that makes no difference. The user agent style sheet is still being applied regardless of the browser. Any ideas why?

Comment: Form me it works, add jsFiddle in the answer below.

Comment: Found some more failure in your css. you forgot some ```{ } ``` Also add ```display: inline;``` to the form ```.example```. Show Fiddle above. Works now!

Comment: I tried the CSS from the Fiddle link above, but it comes up with the old result in my browser. Did you make those changes on there?

Comment: No matter what I do, the console says it is only picking up the user agent stylesheet just for the search button part of the CSS

Comment: it is actually not wanted here, but please send the url over so that I can see the problem live on the server

Comment: Unfortunately it is only on my local machine at the moment. I have worked out that the button element won't read the CSS regardless of the class I assign to it. This leads me to think it is some kind of inheritance problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems there an update in the API or something.

I would suggest to set the overwritten styles an `!important` flag and/or try a browser style-reset:

```
td    /*!important flag*/
{
    border: 1px solid #333 !important;
}

*, html    /*set every element an initial style (style-reset)*/
{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem with a browser reset and important flag is it seems to be overkill, and also the rest of the stylesheet is being applied perfectly, only the search button is redering incorrectly

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is running through a Flask app. might this make a difference?

Comment: maybe that could be a kind of problem, I do not know very much about Flask... flask has its own stylesheets i guess maybe you interfere with them, i only used bootstrap so far.